# Different Lists in different slides scroll at same time

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, vertical-scrolling, ion-slides, ion-list

I have two ionic slides, each containing a regular list. 
My problem is that each time I scroll on one of them, the other scrolls at the same time.

Is there a way of making each list scroll individually?

My code somewhat like this:

```
 <ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
   <ion-slide>
    <ion-list>
    ...
    </ion-list>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
    <ion-list>
    ...
    </ion-list>
   </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
 </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I made it so the ion-content would be inside the slide, so that I could have my ion-lists separated :

```
  <ion-slides>
   <ion-slide>
    <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
      ...
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
   </ion-slide>
   <ion-slide>
    <ion-content>
     <ion-list>
      ...
     </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
   </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Also, I added this css:

```
  ion-slides, ion-slide {
    height: 100% !important;
  }

  .swiper-container {
    margin: unset;
  }
```